# $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \big(\sin(\sin n)\big)^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm trying to evaluate the following series:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \big(\sin(\sin n)\big)^n$$
In this case the terms are not all positive and I don't know if I can your the usual tests.
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \big(\sin(\sin n)\big)^n=0$$ because $\sin n$ is between $1$ and $-1$ ,   $\sin(\sin n)$ is between 1 and -1 , and $ \big(\sin(\sin n)\big)^n $ even smaller and between 1 and -1 too.
Now I don't know what test to use, I tried but with no result.

Comment: What are *sen* and *senn*?

Comment: Most people will find the notation $$\sum^\infty_{n=1}(\sin(\sin n))^n$$ a bit more understandable, I guess.

Comment: Professor.Very much so.Not just a bit:))

Comment: Do you just need to know if it converges to some number $S$ or you need to get an exact value for $S$?

Comment: Assume sen stands for sin, you can use the fact $|\sin(\sin n)| < \sin(1)$ for all $n$ to conclude the series converges absolutely.

Comment: In countries speaking Spanish, "sen" is often used instead of $\sin$.

Comment: You can use root test! And make use of fact that $sin(1)<1$.

Comment: @omkarGirkar I tried the asindotic test ...I'm sure about the root test

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, remind that
$$\sum |a_n|\text{ converges} \quad \implies \quad \sum a_n \text{ converges}.$$

Then use your usual tests to prove the convergence of $\sum |a_n|$.

Moreover, remind that $\sin(x)$ increases when $x\in [-\pi, \pi]\supset [-1,1]$. And is also true that $-1\leq \sin n \leq 1$.

Then
$\sin(-1)\leq \sin\big(\sin n)\big) \leq \sin 1,$
and prove and use the fact that $\sin(1)<1$.